# How to send MDM commands to push an app to iOS device in nodejs

Tags: ios, node.js, apple-push-notifications

I need to push an app through MDM commands. 
With .net to install an app, MDM command is

```
<key>RequestType</key>
<string>InstallApplication</string>
 <key>ManifestURL</key>
     <string>https://domain//static/z21e6gwewUJSflzPFAAFCYQIF6iv0eOtiM5AjiCzE3k3S7Xc2AinK1ONm1jJ3h0O7CiDRNu23V0l_equal_l/ARG/ApplicationRepository/app-102/iPad/1.0.0/manifest.plist</ string>
<key>ManagementFlags</key>
<integer>1</integer>
```

To remove app, the corresponding MDM command is

```
<key>RequestType</key>
<string>RemoveApplication</string>
<key>Identifier</key>
<string>domainSomething.safespace</string>
```

How to implement the same with node-apn module? How to frame the commands? Does it should be XML format or it should be in JSON

Thanks,
Pravin

Answer (score 0):

Apple don't make the documentation for MDM publicly available. You will need to consult the documentation they have supplied. My suspicion is that if they give XML examples then you should always send XML.